# Фиксирование первого столбца table для мобильных?

Tags: css, css3, html5, table

Подскажите, пожалуйста как для разрешений <768px, добавлять горизонтальный скролл для таблици (Ячейки должны быть по 25%) при этом фиксировать первую колонку с названиями атрибутов при горизонтальной прокрутке? Желательно максимально кроссбраузерный метод

```css
.table_attributes {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "MS Sans Serif", Verdana, Helvetica, Arial;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #4d4d4d;
}

.table_attributes thead {
  background-color: rgb(0, 153, 204);
  color: #fff;
}

.table_attributes th {
  text-align: center;
}

.table_attributes th:first-child {
  width: 10%;
  min-width: 120px;
}

.table_attributes .active {
  background-color: #AA002A;
}

.table_attributes tr:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   .table_attributes th{
min-width: 25vw;
  }
  .table_attributes__full {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="table_attributes__full">
<table class="table_attributes">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Тип</th>
      <th>Единица</th>
      <th>WB d150</th>
      <th class="active">WB d160</th>
      <th>WB d200</th>
      <th>WB d250</th>
      <th>WB d315</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Потеря воздуха</td>
    <td>item1</td>
    <td>item1</td>
    <td>item1</td>
    <td>item1</td>
    <td>item1</td>
    <td>item1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cтатическое давление</td>
    <td>item2</td>
    <td>item2</td>
    <td>item2</td>
    <td>item2</td>
    <td>item2</td>
    <td>item2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Акустическое давлениек</td>
    <td>item3item5item5</td>
    <td>item3</td>
    <td>item3</td>
    <td>item3</td>
    <td>item3</td>
    <td>item3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Напряжение </td>
    <td>item4item5 item5item5</td>
    <td>item4</td>
    <td>item4 item5 item5</td>
    <td>item4</td>
    <td>item4</td>
    <td>item4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Обороты мотора</td>
    <td>item5</td>
    <td>item5 item5 item5 item5</td>
    <td>item5</td>
    <td>item5</td>
    <td>item5</td>
    <td>item5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Без геморроя не получится.

Если первая колонка заданной ширины и высота элементов не меняется, можно попробовать ее зафиксировать с помощью `position:fixed`, но пободаться придется знатно. И не факт, что удастся добиться приемлемого результата чистым CSS.

Можно яваскриптом отслеживать скроллинг контейнера с таблицей, применяя к первой колонке таблицы стиль `transform:translateX(***px)`, где *** - число пикселей, на которые проскроллили таблицу.

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем нашёл относительно костыльный метод на CSS. Смысл заключаеться в том что мы "переворачивает" thead и tbody. Фиксируем размер ширины thead и добавляем ему position:absolute; left:0; + надо создать пустые ячейки для первого столбца что б компенсировать отступ. Вообщем вот код

```css
.table_attributes {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "MS Sans Serif", Verdana, Helvetica, Arial;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #4d4d4d;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

table_attributes__second {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.table_attributes thead {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.table_attributes thead tr {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.table_attributes thead th {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table_attributes tbody tr:nth-child(1) td {
  width: 150px;
}

.table_attributes .active {
  background-color: #AA002A!important;
}

.table_attributes th:nth-of-type(even),
.table_attributes tr:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
}

.table_attributes th:first-child,
.table_attributes tr:first-child td {
  background-color: rgb(0, 153, 204);
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .table_attributes td {
    min-width: 25vw;
  }
  .table_attributes__full {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="table_attributes__full">
  <table class="table_attributes">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Тип</th>
        <th>Витрата повітря</th>
        <th>Cтатичний тиск</th>
        <th>Акустичний тиск</th>
        <th>Напруга/частота</th>
        <th>Обороти двигуна</th>
        <th>Потужність</th>
        <th>Витрата потужності</th>
        <th>Макc. робоча темп.</th>
        <th>Bага</th>
        <th>Степінь захисту</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>item1</td>
        <td class="active">item1</td>
        <td>item1</td>
        <td>item1</td>
        <td>item1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>item2</td>
        <td>item2</td>
        <td>item2</td>
        <td>item2</td>
        <td>item2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>item3</td>
        <td>item3</td>
        <td>item3</td>
        <td>item3</td>
        <td>item3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>item4</td>
        <td>item4</td>
        <td>item4</td>
        <td>item4</td>
        <td>item4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>item5</td>
        <td>item5</td>
        <td>item5</td>
        <td>item5</td>
        <td>item5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>item6</td>
        <td>item6</td>
        <td>item6</td>
        <td>item6</td>
        <td>item6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>item7</td>
        <td>item7</td>
        <td>item7</td>
        <td>item7</td>
        <td>item7</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>item8</td>
        <td>item8</td>
        <td>item8</td>
        <td>item8</td>
        <td>item8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>item9</td>
        <td>item9</td>
        <td>item9</td>
        <td>item9</td>
        <td>item9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>item10</td>
        <td>item10</td>
        <td>item10</td>
        <td>item10</td>
        <td>item10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>item11</td>
        <td>item11</td>
        <td>item11</td>
        <td>item11</td>
        <td>item11</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```